# How to set focus on the last record which was selected prior to opening a new form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form which allows the user to browse records on Form #1 and by selecting a record, one can enriched it further by clicking an individual record which then opens form #2 to allow the user to add additional details.  My issue occurs after making the ammendments on form#2 for upon closing it, the focus is automatically set to the first record available in form #1.   I would like to understand how to set focus on the last record which was viewed prior to opening form #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close Form2, are you requerying Form1? If so, then you'll have to store the ID value of the current record in Form1 prior to that requery, and then use FindFirst to locate it after your requery:

```
Dim intID As Integer
intID = Forms("Form1").YourIDField 
' requery, or whatever, here
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst "YourIDField=" & intID
If Not rst.NoMatch Then
  Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark
End If
```